# ¿Cómo llenar un combo box con una consulta sql haciendo referencia a uno de los dos registros de otro combobox vba?

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy haciendo un formulario con vba en excel con unos combo box dependientes, tengo uno que muestra las empresas con su id y su nombre y lo que quiero es que cuando seleccione la empresa en el combo box pase solo el id de la empresa a otro combo box para que me muestre solo los  resultados que le pertenecen a esa empresa, este es mi godigo:

Código combo box empresa:

```
Private Sub comboEmpresa_Enter()
    Me.comboEmpresa.Clear
    
    sql = "select id_empresa, nombre_empresa from cat_empresas where empresa_activo = 1 order by 1 asc;"
    
    Call conn  'aqui llamo mi conexion a la bd
    
    Dim cmd As ADODB.command
        Set cmd = New ADODB.command
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        
        With cmd
            .ActiveConnection = cn
            .CommandType = adCmdText
            .CommandText = sql
            Set rs = .Execute(adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText)
            
        End With
        Set cmd = Nothing
        
        Do While Not rs.EOF()
            
            valor1 = rs.Fields("id_empresa").Value
            valor2 = rs.Fields("nombre_empresa ").Value
            
            Me.comboEmpresa.Object.AddItem valor1 & " - " & valor2
            rs.MoveNext
       Loop
        
        
        rs.Close
        cn.Close
        
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Este es el código del otro combo box que es dependiente del de empresa:

```
Private Sub comboCultivo_Enter()
    Me.comboCultivo.Clear    

    
    sql = "select id_cultivo, nombre_cultivo  from cat_cultivos_erp where id_empresa = " & (valor del id_empresa del otro combo) & " and activo_cultivo = 1 order by 2 asc;"
    
    Call conn 'aqui llamo mi conexion a la bd
    
    Dim cmd As ADODB.command
        Set cmd = New ADODB.command
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        
        With cmd
            .ActiveConnection = cn
            .CommandType = adCmdText
            .CommandText = sql
            Set rs = .Execute(adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText)
            
        End With
        Set cmd = Nothing
        
        Do While Not rs.EOF()

            valor1 = rs.Fields("id_cultivo").Value
            valor2 = rs.Fields("nombre_cultivo").Value
            
            Me.comboCultivo.Object.AddItem valor1 & " - " & valor2
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        
        rs.Close
        cn.Close
        
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Intente varias formas de pasar ese valor separado pero no me muestra nada. En el primer combo box si me muestra datos de esta forma:

> ```
> 1 - Empresa1
> 2 - Empresa2
> 3 - Empresa3
> ```

Comment: gracias y saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude encontrar una solución, dejo el código por si alguien tiene el mismo problema:

```
Private Sub comboEmpresa_Enter()
    Me.comboEmpresa.Clear   

    sql = "select id_empresa, nombre_empresa from cat_empresas where activo_empresa = 1 order by 2 asc;"
    
    Call conn
    
    Dim cmd As ADODB.command
     Set cmd = New ADODB.command
     Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
     rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
     
     With cmd
         .ActiveConnection = cn
         .CommandType = adCmdText
         .CommandText = sql
         Set rs = .Execute(adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText)
         
     End With
     
      Dim recordCount As Long
    recordCount = 0
    
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        recordCount = recordCount + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
      If recordCount > 0 Then
        ReDim MyArray(1 To recordCount, 1 To 2)'aqui redimensiono mi array a solo dos columnas
        
        rs.MoveFirst
        Dim x As Long
        x = 1
        
        ' obtengo en mi array mis dos campos
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            MyArray(x, 1) = rs.Fields("id_empresa").Value
            MyArray(x, 2) = rs.Fields("nombre_empresa").Value
            x = x + 1
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray, 1)
            Me.comboEmpresa.AddItem MyArray(i, 2) 'solo la columna a mostrar en mi combobox
        Next i
    End If
       
     rs.Close
     cn.Close
     
     Set rs = Nothing
     Set cn = Nothing
End Sub

'en este sub de mi comboEmpresa pero tipo change obtengo el id de mi consulta y lo paso a un label oculto de mi form

Private Sub comboEmpresa_Change()
    Dim Indice As Integer
    Indice = Me.comboEmpresa.ListIndex
    If Indice >= 0 Then
        Me.labelempresa.Caption = MyArray(Indice + 1, 1)'mando al label oculto el id
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

En el segundo combo box paso el id de la empresa que se mando al label

```
Private Sub comboCultivo_Enter()
    Me.comboCultivo.Clear    

    
    sql = "select nombre_cultivo  from cat_cultivos_erp where id_empresa = " & Me.labelempresa.Caption & " and activo_cultivo = 1 order by 2 asc;"
    
    Call conn 'aqui llamo mi conexion a la bd
    
    Dim cmd As ADODB.command
        Set cmd = New ADODB.command
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        
        With cmd
            .ActiveConnection = cn
            .CommandType = adCmdText
            .CommandText = sql
            Set rs = .Execute(adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText)
            
        End With
        Set cmd = Nothing
        
        Do While Not rs.EOF()            
            Me.comboCultivo.AddItem rs("nombre_cultivo")
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        
        rs.Close
        cn.Close
        
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```